# How to put divs above each other inside a container?

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to put four elements inside a container div; I have problem with div 2 and div 3, I can not put them above each other! so how to put 2 divs above each other inside a container in this situation?

[image: idea]

HTML:

```
<div class = "Container"> 
   <div class = "Div1" > </div>
   <div class = "Div_Mid!!" > </div>    
   <div class = "Div4" > </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
   .Container {height: 15px;width: 50%;float: left;}

   .Div1 {height: 15px;width: 20%;float: right;}

   .Div4 {height: 15px;width: 20%;float: left;}

   .Div2  {height: 15px;width: 20%;float: ??????????}
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant parts of your HTML and CSS please? That way we can give specific advice rather than generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this basic layout and insert your HTML into it. I have added borders to all divs for visibility of the div sizes, please ignore that.

```css
div{
  border:1px solid black;
}
.container{
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display:  flex;
}
.left{
  width:33.33333333333333%;
  float: left;
}
.center{
  width:33.33333333333333%;
  float:left;
}
.right{
  width:33.33333333333333%;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    left div
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <div>top div</div>
    <div>bottom div</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    right
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was diving in this special case when I was building my own CSS library, basically this is the CSS/HTML pseudo code I came up with:

```
Div 0 | position relative
  Div 4 | float left
  /Div 4

  Div 2 | position relative
  /Div 2

  Div 3
  /Div 3

  Div 1 | position absolute; top 0; right 0
  /Div 1
/Div 0
```

(you might need to specify all divs as `box-sizing: border-box` but I don't think it is needed)

Down below is a snippet demonstrating this.

```css
body{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
    
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

slot{
  color: #e9ebee;
  text-align: center;
}

[class*="w"],
[class*="h"],
[class*="mw"],
[class*="mh"]{
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow: auto;
  
  float: left;
}

.fl{ float: left; }

.rel{  position: relative; }
[class*="abs-"]{ position: absolute; }
.abs-t{ top: 0px; }
.abs-r{ right: 0px; }

.h12, .mh12{ height: 100vh; }
.h2, .mh2{ height: calc( 2 * (100vh / 12)); }
.h8, .mh8{ height: calc( 8 * (100vh / 12)); }

.w1{ width: calc(100vw / 12); }
.w1{ width: calc(10 * (100vw / 12)); }
.mw2{ width: calc(2 * (100vw / 12)); }
.mw8{ width: calc(8 * (100vw / 12)); }
```

```html
<body>
 
 <slot class="h12 w1 mw2 mh12 fl" style="background: #ff0000;">div 4</slot>
 <slot class="h2 w10 mw8 mh2 rel" style="background: #00ff00;">div 2</slot>
 <slot class="h2 w10 mw8 mh2" style="background: #ff00ff;">div 3</slot>
 <slot class="h8 w10 mw8 mh8" style="background: #ffff00;"></slot>
 <slot class="h12 w1 mw2 mh12 abs-r abs-t" style="background: #0000ff;">div 1</slot>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with flex, with 3 divs left center and right with `flex-direction: column` on the centered div so that child divs stack on each other:

Example:

```css
div {
  border: 3px solid black;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
  margin: 10px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  flex: 1
}

.center {
  flex: 2;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.right {
  flex: 1
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    Div 4
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <div>Div 2</div>
    <div>Div 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    Div 1
  </div>
</div>
<div>
    Div 0
</div>
```

Hope this helps!